# Debian 11 install Cuda Toolkit and CuDNN

Tags: debian, driver, nvidia

System: Debian 11
GPU: Quadro k5200
For running the TensorFlow on my GPU I have to install Nvidia stack like Cuda Toolkit and CuDNN. After Debian 11 installation I executed the following step:

1. Using apt I installed the Kernel Headers
2. Using apt I Installed the GCC
3. I added to the file: /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf the following values:

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist nvidia-173
blacklist nvidia-96
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-173-updates
blacklist nvidia-96-updates
alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

4. After this I pressed `ctrl + alt + F1`
5. I typed `sudo service lightdm stop`
6. Using `sudo apt install cuda` I Installed the Cuda Toolkit. During the installation process I saw the warning about Nouveau.

After restart, the system doesn’t boot and shows the following message: `Faild to start Light Display Manager.`

Why didn't the drivers from Cuda boot up? How to install Cuda and CuDNN on Debian 11 correctly?